# Draggable React typescript extends Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, draggable

I’m a beginner in React and Typescript. Wanna make some cool opened window with Drag effect. Find draggable package but I don’t understand how to use it like extend component.

Writing from the phone. But will be glad to see some helps…

I’m find a lot of posts with JS but I can’t find some examples for TS. Please - can some one give me a small example, how I can use simple Drag effect with this package in export component :(

Comment: All of the JavaScript solutions apply to TypeScript. Since you're a self-declared beginner in the language, this is the first rule - learn it well. All JS is Valid TS.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

As Aluan mentioned: **All TS is JS under the hood so you can use JS files within TS projects without error**, they are just untyped. If you try to use TS in a JS project, however, this will not work and needs to be converted.

### Solution

The solution you're looking for can be done in various ways. Here is an example using Prime React and TSX.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog } from 'primereact/dialog';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';

interface DraggableDialogProps {
  visible: boolean;
  onHide: () => void;
}

const DraggableDialog: React.FC<DraggableDialogProps> = ({ visible, onHide }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ top: 50, left: 50 });

  const handleDrag = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    setPosition({
      top: e.clientY,
      left: e.clientX,
    });
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      header="Draggable Dialog"
      visible={visible}
      style={{ width: '300px', position: 'absolute', top: `${position.top}px`, left: `${position.left}px` }}
      onHide={onHide}
      draggable
      onDrag={(e) => handleDrag(e)}
    >
      <div>
        <p>This is some basic content in a draggable dialog.</p>
      </div>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [dialogVisible, setDialogVisible] = useState(false);

  const showDialog = () => {
    setDialogVisible(true);
  };

  const hideDialog = () => {
    setDialogVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button label="Show Dialog" onClick={showDialog} />
      <DraggableDialog visible={dialogVisible} onHide={hideDialog} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you'd like to use my example and prime react then make sure to add the library:

```
npm install primereact primeicons
```

### Solution 2 (not suggested):

But if you want to create you're own without the use of any 3rd party (again not suggested) you can do something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, MouseEvent } from 'react';
import './CustomDraggableDialog.css'; // Add your custom styles

interface CustomDraggableDialogProps {
  onClose: () => void;
}

const CustomDraggableDialog: React.FC<CustomDraggableDialogProps> = ({ onClose, children }) => {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const dialogRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleMouseDown = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    setIsDragging(true);
    const offsetX = e.clientX - position.x;
    const offsetY = e.clientY - position.y;

    const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      setPosition({ x: e.clientX - offsetX, y: e.clientY - offsetY });
    };

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
      setIsDragging(false);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`custom-draggable-dialog ${isDragging ? 'dragging' : ''}`}
      style={{ top: position.y, left: position.x }}
      ref={dialogRef}
    >
      <div className="header" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
        <span>Drag me</span>
        <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
      </div>
      <div className="content">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomDraggableDialog;
```

and add the css

```css
.custom-draggable-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.custom-draggable-dialog.dragging {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.header {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: grab;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

### Note To Author:

I see you're a new contributor, welcome! [Here's a friendly link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that explains how to treat answers to your questions!